# Eliminate duplicate code and generalize method for populating Lists with different object types

Tags: c#, .net

Since the title may not be clear enough. I want to create a method or set of methods to generalize my SQL queries. Currently I create a function that populates a `List<T>` etc.

```cs
 SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString");
 string command = "   exec dbo.MyProcedure ";
 SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(command, cnn);
 // maybe some parameters here to pass to the procedure
```

Most of the functions created look something like this:

```cs
try
{
  cnn.Open();
  using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
  {
     while (reader.Read())
     {
       MyList.Add(reader[0].ToString());
     }
  }
  cnn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   lw.Log_Write("Something went wrong. " + ex.Message);
   if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
      cnn.Close();
}
```

Since this is something i repeat a lot in my project, I would like to know a good way to eliminate the duplicate code for readability and easier maintenance.

Edit:
The problem I have is populating a `List<T>` since it won't always be `List<string>`.For example, sometimes I need to populate the list with `CheckBox` items which must have their `Content` property set to the data being read etc.

Comment: Sounds like your are searching for a framework, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/ - if you want to do it on your own, what is your exact problem / question?

Comment: I don't know If a framework is what I need since it offers a lot more than I currently need. What would be the best way for me to make the above code reusable and to prevent a lot of code duplication?

Comment: The good thing about libs is, that they invested lots of time to offer you those functionality but ok, you want to write it yourself. The answer to "how do I prevent code duplication" is: Write a helper method that accepts "what should be different" as parameters and does the job for you. SO is not a code writing service, so what have you tried so far and what exactly was the problem, why it didn't work?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Your comment helped me realize what the true issue was and I corrected the question accordingly. I haven't tried to code this yet but I should be trying this today after work.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is to use the generic method to convert a Datatable to any list of objects. The code below does this and also maps according to the type of fields in your list.

There is only one specific detail, the fields in your list must have exactly the same names as the columns returned in your Datatable.

This code is an extension of a DataTable:

```
public static void ConvertTo<T>(this DataTable datatable, ref List<T> ret, params object[] param)
    {
        if (datatable == null || datatable.Rows.Count == 0) { return; }

        try
        {
            List<T> lstT = new List<T>();
            var lstPropertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperties();

            foreach (DataRow objDataRow in datatable.Rows)
            {
                T objT;

                if (param != null && param.Length > 0)
                {
                    objT = (T)System.Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), param);
                }
                else
                {
                    objT = (T)System.Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
                }
                


                foreach (PropertyInfo objPropertyInfo in (from objPropertyInfo1 in lstPropertyInfo
                                                          where objPropertyInfo1 != null && objPropertyInfo1.CanWrite
                                                          where datatable.Columns.Contains(objPropertyInfo1.Name)
                                                          where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(objDataRow[objPropertyInfo1.Name].ToString().Trim())
                                                          select objPropertyInfo1))
                {

                    var propertyType = objPropertyInfo.PropertyType;
                    if (propertyType.IsGenericType)
                    {
                        propertyType = propertyType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
                    }


                    if (propertyType == typeof(Boolean))
                    {
                        objPropertyInfo.SetValue(objT, Convert.ToBoolean(objDataRow[objPropertyInfo.Name]), null);
                    }
                    else if (propertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                    {
                        objPropertyInfo.SetValue(objT, DateTime.Parse(objDataRow[objPropertyInfo.Name].ToString()), null);
                    }

                    else if (propertyType == typeof(String))
                    {
                        objPropertyInfo.SetValue(objT, objDataRow[objPropertyInfo.Name].ToString().Trim(), null);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        objPropertyInfo.SetValue(objT, Convert.ChangeType(objDataRow[objPropertyInfo.Name].ToString().Trim(), propertyType), null);
                    }

                }

                lstT.Add(objT);
            }

            ret = lstT;

        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }


    }
```

**Note that in the code I mapped the conversion of only a few types, but you can do it for any type you need.**

Here is an example of using the method:

```
 DataTable data = YourMethodReturningADataTable();
        
 List<MyObject> Test = null;
 data.ConvertTo<MyObject>(ref Test);
```